# dynamically created dropdown multiple appends don't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<select>` which I dynamically create.
When I click a button, this should be added to the end of the div. However, when I click multiple times, it isn't added multiple times, while I expected it to.

Full code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Recipe</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name, hiddenId, inputName){
  if(name == 'New'){
    document.getElementById(hiddenId).innerHTML='New: <input type="text" name="other" />';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(hiddenId).innerHTML='';
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectBox = document.createElement("select");

      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Chocolade: Zwart";
      option.value = "1-1";
      selectBox.add(option);


      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Zuivel: Boter(80%)";
      option.value = "2-2";
      selectBox.add(option);


      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Zuivel: Room(40%)";
      option.value = "2-3";
      selectBox.add(option);


      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Smaakmakers: Koffie-extract";
      option.value = "3-4";
      selectBox.add(option);



function addNewIngredient(divId){
  var amountPart = "Amount(in kg or l): <input type=\"text\"/>";
  console.log("clicked");
    //document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(selectBox + amountPart + '<br/>');
    document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(selectBox);
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="/new/recipe">
  category: <select name="category" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, 'newCategory')">
              <option value="NONE">Please select ....</option>
              <option value="New">New</option>
            </select>
  <div id="newCategory"></div><br/>
  <div id="ingredientList"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="addNewIngredient('ingredientList')" value="Add Ingredient"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w42m6voj/

PS: HTML is generated by Bottle(python framework). I do not hardcode the values in the options, they are fetched from a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created just one instance of selectbox:

```
var selectBox = document.createElement("select");
```

And then you reuse it. So it's being removed from the old place in DOM and inserted into another.

Here is how it can work:

```
function createNewSelectBox() {
    var selectBox = document.createElement("select");

      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Chocolade: Zwart";
      option.value = "1-1";
      selectBox.add(option);


      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Zuivel: Boter(80%)";
      option.value = "2-2";
      selectBox.add(option);


      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Zuivel: Room(40%)";
      option.value = "2-3";
      selectBox.add(option);


      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Smaakmakers: Koffie-extract";
      option.value = "3-4";
      selectBox.add(option);

    return selectBox;
}



function addNewIngredient(divId){
  var amountPart = "Amount(in kg or l): <input type=\"text\"/>";
  console.log("clicked");
    //document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(selectBox + amountPart + '<br/>');
    document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(createNewSelectBox());
}
```

Comment: u beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know it worked like that :( The more you know :D

Comment: @SajjanSarkar, sorry, got lucky :)

Comment: @ShadowFlame, sure :). Accept the answer if you think it's helpful.

Comment: just did, couldn't yet due to time constraints :D